# useState is one step behind on switch onValueChange

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

so i am rendering a switch that has to toggle the value of

```
const [useBioAuth, setUseBioAuth] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

this is my switch

```
 <Switch
     onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
     trackColor={{ true: colors.secondary }}
     thumbColor={colors.input.bg.normal}
     style={style.marginT10}
     value={useBioAuth}
  />
```

and this is my toggleSwitch function

```
const toggleSwitch = useCallback(() => {
    setUseBioAuth(!useBioAuth);
    console.log('toggle '+ useBioAuth)
    _storeData();
  }, [_storeData, useBioAuth]);

  const _storeData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('useBioAuth', JSON.stringify(useBioAuth));
      if (!useBioAuth) {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('useBioAuth');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      //TODO
    }
  }, [useBioAuth]);
```

however the state is always one step behind of the toggle the console log shows true when it should be false and vice versa

any ideas please ? 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function instead of a value in `setState`. So try this:
[image]